# Logic Math Puzzle - Help me solving this - C++

Tags: c++, arrays, math, logic, processing-efficiency

I have following C++ array: `int arr[20][20]` filled with numbers from 1 to 5

A specific element, for example arr[5][8] is set as start point

I have to find all elements in the array, that have the same value and that are "touching" (vert/horiz) the start point

I could search through the array with three for loops, but this would result in 20*20+20*2=1600 deplacements through the array

I hope I explained the problem well enough for you to understand

i.stack.imgur.com/j3e0e.jpg

All red marked elements should be found

Comment: I don't know where you get your numbers but this could be fairly simple. Just create an empty [2][400] array and pass it with the starting point to a function. Remove the starting point in that function and add it to your array. There are 4 possible touching elements. For each that have the value call the function recursively.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with nearly linear time if you use Union Find algorithm.
Have a look at this:
http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/15uf/UF.java.html